# Informatica 10 Big Data Edtion trial version

Tags: version, informatica, informatica-powercenter, bigdata

please can any one help me to get the trial version of Informatica Big Data Edition 10 version.

i tried looking at it but i didn't!!

Help me folks

Answer (score 1):

Informatica is providing and AWS instance with BYOL, Check the below link for more information, this is not exactly a trial/free version, anyways worth checking this (Copied the content also, just in-case you do not have access to Informatica network

https://network.informatica.com/thread/60893

Content replicated from the above link

"There has been changes to the Trial edition and here is the latest update from the PM team on the same

We are no longer offering Trial editions for BDM and DQ through marketplace. Customers can use our One-Click install from Amazon Marketplace / community, but it is BYOL (Bring your own license). So, they will have to reach out to their Informatica rep for a trial license. With one-click everything will be automatically installed and configured. So, customers will have a ready-to-use BDM image.

Here are the links for the Amazon Marketplace and Community:

https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/informatica-bdm/

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01MY0DZO7?qid=1488489044722&sr=0-1&ref_=srh_res_product_title

Hope this helps. "

Regards
Raj